# @session.get not working in scala html template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I have my @session.get("id") not working below. after logging into the system, I set the session value id with .withSession("id" -> id) in my controllers. Is there a way to get this session.get working?

**main.scala.html**

@(title: String)(content: Html)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" cantent="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimun-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>@title</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="main container">
    <div class="navigation container">
      <div class="logo container">
        <div class="user">@session.get("id")</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <ul>
      <li class="user"><a href="@routes.AdmnTask.user()">USER</a></li>
      <li class="code"><a href="@routes.AdmnTask.code_list()">CODE</a></li>
           </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <a class="right" href="#all-menu"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="mainnav" class="mainnav">
        @content
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This cause not found: value session error. Same not found issue even after adding

```
@()(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session)
```

And this is my **index.scala.html** which becomes a basic structure of my templates.

```
@*
 * This template takes a single argument, a String containing a
 * message to display.
 *@
@(message: String)

@*
 * Call the `main` template with two arguments. The first
 * argument is a `String` with the title of the page, the second
 * argument is an `Html` object containing the body of the page.
 *@
@main("Welcome") {

    @*
     * Get an `Html` object by calling the built-in Play welcome
     * template and passing a `String` message.
     *@
    @message

}
```

Please Help!

Comment: It is possible to pass the `(implicit request: Request[_])` to the template, then you can use `request.session`

Comment: you mean i should add (implicit request: Request[_]) next to @(title: String)(content: Html) at my main.scala.html? and use @request.session.get("id")?

Comment: that causes `Cannot find any HTTP Request here` error in every other @content pages

Comment: In the `Action` you can provide implicit request like `Action { implicit req => ??? }`

Comment: I already have `= Action { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>` in my controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the session to your template:

vies.htlm.index(message,session) from your action. And then further pass this session to your main.scala.html.

And in index.scala.html, remove implicit from the session parameter.

Or, pass (implicit request: Request[T]) in your index.scala.html and also in your main.scala.html.

```
@(message: String)(implicit request: Request[T]) -> index
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit request: Request[T]) -> main
```

You can access the session like:

```
request.session.get("key")
```

This will do the needful.

Comment: what is Request[T] exactly? This causes not found: type T error.

Comment: in your case use -> implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent]

Comment: I guess i need some action in controller to make this request work and not sure what it is.

Comment: you have this implicit request in your action from where you are calling your index.html. just add this in your templates[index and main] as well: 
(implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent])

Comment: then this index page requires me to have more arguments at @main("welcome)

Comment: error message - 
not enough arguments for method apply: (title: String, session: play.api.mvc.Session)(content: play.twirl.api.Html)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.MessagesRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object main.
Unspecified value parameter session.

Comment: and this index page is to form the basic structure of playframe, and this main.scala is for the global navigation bar purpose only.  I have different html, which will be put in @content in main.scala.html

Comment: let's assume that you are calling index.scala.html from your action: 
 Action { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>Ok(views.scala.html("some message"))}, Now, put this in your index.scala.html -> @(message: String)(implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent]). And since you've to access the session in main.scala.html, put this in your main.scala.html -> @(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent])

Comment: If you're using requests in your templates then you don't need to pass session while calling your template

Comment: Not so sure what this index and main really mean, but followed what is given by this framework. (probably, not so well) .
I am actually calling different html pages, for instance, team.scala.html. this after this page is up, this goes into @content in main.scala.html. 

not sure what index.scala.html really do but this just is what i have as a base.

Comment: okay, then add this -> @(message: String)(implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent]), to your team.scala.html. and since you need your to access the session in main.scala.html, you need to also add  (implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent]) in your main.scala.html.

Comment: great! it works well now. after adding implicit request in all the other html pages where i used to have implicit request: MessageRequest~~. 

I have one more question @geek94, this session thing has to last until the user close the browser in scala/play. but mine doesn't. Possible guess for this reason?